# TypeScript: Bound function loses overloads

Tags: typescript

I'm having a problem with a function that has overloads and is bound before usage.
If it is used directly, everything is fine, but when I use it via another function that first binds it, it doesn't recognize all of the possible overloads, except the last one (the one just before the implementation).

(This problem appeared suddenly even though at time of committing nothing rose. Perhaps the TS server was napping at the time.)

example:

```
function fn(arg1: any, arg2: { id: number }): void
function fn(arg1: any, arg2: { value: string }): void
function fn(arg1: any, arg2: { id: number } | { value: string }) { }

function useFn() {
    const arg1 = 'some predefined arg'
    return fn.bind(null, arg1)
}

const myFn = useFn()

myFn({ id: 3 }) // ts doesnt know this overload
/* 
Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ value: string; }'.
 */
```

[playground-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAhgJwOYEYBci6YAngDRE4BMhA3ojACaFggC2ARgKaaIC%20ASkIA3OEwCwAKFCRYCZGix5CxcpWw1E9YegA2ILoQDOUTDDDZ%20QxKInTw0eEhQYcBIqQpLN9Ji3bcvHyIAD5aNnoGxqbmloLhfFJSMo7yIEZcAGJoAlpSAJAQCCbquIgAvIgA5EZwbFyIAA6YXIxcwOat6lUFLVAgmM5gAHQc5oyorLq6Xm4CUomSUkVgJWwk2RWI6Vk5SZLr2ai%20zIgAzFaIAPRXiFBGiIxwXEZgUIgA1mBwAO53ABYwB5wYQ8XRwdCMKRXABUiCkAEEcOwuG9EHBgHcSI0GlUTv5ODwANz8KoMB7fd7oIxGGDYMDoDi6BpQOBNLDoepQHjozFQbG47SRQyIExmCwkvhVYZSRAwq5AA)

Comment: This is a known design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#38353](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38353).  Overloads and inference don't play nicely. If you want different behavior you should rewrite your overloaded function, unfortunately.  1st choice is make the function not an overload (e.g., accept the union in the param), 2nd choice is to add a "catch-all" overload at the end (that would be the union). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the ref! (sadly i didnt find any myself),
the suggested choices are not providing what i really wanted to acheive - the inference,
i want ts to warn and autocomplete based on partial argument.
is it possible, without overloading, somehow?

Comment: Hmm, the thing you "really wanted to achieve" isn't mentioned anywhere in the question.  Is this an XY problem?  I'm happy to write up an answer here to the question as asked, which I believe is "unfortunately this is a known limitation", or you can [edit] the question to not talk about overloads at all and instead ask about what you're really trying to accomplish and I might take a look when you're done.  How would you like to proceed?